# How do I generate an html string from group by

Tags: c#, linq

Here I have a list from my class Assinantes

```
new Assinante
            {
                City= "BAURU",
                Num= 112,
                ClientCode= 3123,
                Phone= "1412345675"
            },
            new Assinante
            {
                City= "BAURU",
                Num= 45,
                ClientCode= 3123,
                Phone= "214464347"
            }
```

And I needed to group by City, ClientCod and Num, which I've already done here:

```
var listGroup= (from a in lista
            group a by new {a.City, a.ClientCode, a.Num});
```

Then, I needed to generate an html string with Linq, like the example below:

```
<div>
   <h2>Bauru</h2>
   <ul>
        <li>3123</li>
        <ul>
            <li>112</li>
            <ul>
                <li>1412345675</li>
            </ul>
            <li>45</li>
            <ul>
                <li>214464347</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Could somebody give me any sugestion?

Comment: Why are you building an html string using C#? Just asking because depending on your problem there may be a better solution

Comment: Because I'll send an email with this html to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can generate desired html using `XElement`. i suppose my sample can be re-written with Linq method Aggregate, but i prefer nested foreach due to more readable code

[fiddle with demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GNKANy)

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
...
        var xml = new XElement("div");

        foreach(var city in lst.GroupBy(x=>x.City))
        {
            var cityXml = new XElement("h2", city.Key);
            var cityUl = new XElement("ul");                
            foreach(var client in city.GroupBy(c=>c.ClientCode))
            {
                var clientXml = new XElement("li", client.Key);
                var clientUl = new XElement("ul");

                foreach(var num in client.GroupBy(cl=>cl.Num))
                {
                    var numXml = new XElement("li", num.Key);
                    var numUl = new XElement("ul");                     
                    foreach(var phone in num)
                    {
                        numUl.Add(new XElement("li",phone.Phone));
                    }
                    clientUl.Add(numXml);
                    clientUl.Add(numUl);
                }                   
                cityUl.Add(clientXml);
                cityUl.Add(clientUl);
            }
            xml.Add(cityXml);
            xml.Add(cityUl);
        }

        string res = xml.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq to xml for this issue, also included in the example options to add attributes, which could possibly be useful in the future (styling or querying)

```
var html =  new XElement("div", new XAttribute("class","dynamic-content"), 
                    from i in lst.GroupBy(x=>new{x.City,x.ClientCode,x.Num}) select 
                        new XElement("div",new XAttribute("class","city"),
                            new XElement("h1",new XAttribute("class","city-name"), i.Key.City ),
                            new XElement("ul",
                                from k in i.GroupBy(a=>a.ClientCode) select
                                        new XElement("li", 
                                            new XElement("h4",new XAttribute("class","client-code"), k.Key),
                                            new XElement("ul",
                                                from j in k.GroupBy(a=>a.Num) select 
                                                    new XElement("li", 
                                                        new XAttribute("class","client-num"), j.Key ,
                                                        new XElement("ul", new XAttribute("class","phone-numbers"), 
                                                            from l in j select 
                                                                new XElement("li", new XAttribute("class","phone-number"), l.Phone)
                                                    )
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                            )
                        )
            );
```

To get the actual string just use `html.ToString()`

see fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F9SkEK)

Comment: using of XElement is excellent, but the result differs from html, given in question

Comment: @ASh how does the output differ? would there be a workaround? didn't get a chance to test the output, so additional insight would be useful

Comment: to start with, thml is `IEnumerable<XElement>()`;`string.Join(Environment.NewLine,html)` is equal to <div>
  <h1>BAURU</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>112<ul><li>1412345675</li></ul></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>BAURU</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>45<ul><li>214464347</li></ul></li>
  </ul>
</div>

Comment: @konkked Thanks for helping me, but in your answer missed the ClientCode. I didn't know how to use that XElement, thanks in advance. Sorry for the broken english.

Comment: @MauroMaciel Thanks for the heads up, made some changes to include classes to the html as well